# Using ajax to send JSON to an action, parameter is null (returns internal server error 500)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to use ajax and JSON to get a result back from an action, and where it's working perfectly fine on different pages/actions, this one just won't work.

My Javascript:

```
var lookup = $("#textbox").val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/GetId',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: lookup,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        result = data;
    }
});
```

My action:

```
public ActionResult GetId(string lookup)
{
    ActionResult result = View();

    Order order =
        db.Orders
            .Where(o => o.Code == lookup)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    result = Json(order.Id.ToString());

    return result;
}
```

Now, I've seen the following situations, all of which I can't really explain:

1. With the code as above, console.log will display everything fine, the Ajax method throws a 500 internal server error and my breakpoint in my action is *not* hit (like the action is not called or something?).
2. With the code as above, except using **JSON.stringify** around lookup, my breakpoint *is* hit, but the parameter is NULL. When I continue to debug through the action, the debugger.exe will freeze and crash.

I have a similar situation on a different page, it posts a list as JSON.stringify, my action saves it to the db and returns a result message. This works perfectly fine! I'm completely stumped as to why the above won't work.

**Edit**
I've narrowed it down (just a little bit): turns out the Error 500 Internal Server Error was being thrown because the code inside my action did not handle a null value correctly. Since the parameter is always null, because the JSON isn't sent (correctly), it would always break/crash. I've added a catch now, so JSON will correctly return an error now (saying that my order could not be found).

**Edit2**
I'm not sure why this situation doesn't work, while my other does. But, the solution was to pass a model instead of a plain string and using stringify on the entire model. Finally, my action needed to accept a model as well:

```
var lookup = { lookup: $("#textbox").val() };

$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/GetId',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(lookup),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        result = data;
    }
});

public ActionResult GetId(Order model)
{
    ActionResult result = View();

    Order order =
        db.Orders
            .Where(o => o.Lookup == model.Lookup)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    result = Json(order.Id.ToString());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try `data: {lookup: lookup}`

Comment: Best practices says that you should use Html.URL() method to generate url instead of hardcoding as "url: '/Controller/GetId'".

Comment: just see your controller name is "controller"..???

Comment: The name isn't actually Controller.

Comment: He would've gotten a 404 if the controller name was wrong.

Comment: he is getting 505..internal server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var lookup = $("#textbox").val();

$.ajax({
  url: '/Controller/GetId',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {lookup: JSON.stringify(lookup)}, // change this
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (data) {
    result = data;
  }
});
```

Comment: It works almost like this, except I had to JSON.stringify the entire model, not just the value I set to the lookup property. But this put me on the right track, thank you.

Comment: It wasn't clear what you model was, but I find it easier if you just use `$.post('/Controller/GetId', { lookup: $('#textbox').val() }, function () {...});` (the `$.post()` function will work it all out for you - and in this case if you only want a single value, it saves posting back the whole model

Answer (score 1):

I got this working approach all over my code:

```
var oldSearchId = '@ViewBag.OldSearchId';
var description = $("#Description").val();
var model = { oldSearchId: oldSearchId, newSearchName: searchName, newSearchDescription: description };
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveSearchAs", "Search")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: JSON.stringify(model)
})
```

Note the model creation is JS way and then used in `JSON.Stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as :

```
result = Json(order.Id.ToString(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and correct url as :

```
url: '/Controller/GetId',  <---instead of 'Controller' give your controller name here
```

and there is one more problem in your case is that you are using  `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` means you are sending json in your ajax request and your `data:lookup` is not proper json then use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to proper Json format.

Comment: I'm not sure what this does, but my code breaks before I even reach that line - like I said, my parameter (string lookup) is NULL when I debug. This means the JSON data is not passed (correctly).

Comment: That gives me the error "Invalid JSON primitive" during serialization

Comment: strange...the ajax method which you have posted in your question is exact which you are using...???...@IvoCoumans

Comment: @IvoCoumans...just remove  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',...and it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lookup = $("#textbox").val();

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetId", "Controller")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: lookup,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        result = data;
    }
});
```